# Attribute error '/posts/' 'Comment' object has no attribute '_mptt_meta'

Tags: html, django, django-mptt, django-comments

I am following [this](https://martinfitzpatrick.name/article/django-threaded-comments/) example on how to set threaded comments with django_comments and django-mptt.

I have followed most of it and the posted comments are working in admin but I am getting this error 'Comment' object has no attribute '_mptt_meta'. I have tried using a different instances to reference with and tried different objects but I am not sure what the problem might be?

I have a comments app where I am running most of the code from in this example:

comments/models.py:

```
from django_comments.models import Comment
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey


class MPTTComment(MPTTModel, Comment):
""" Threaded comments - Add support for the parent comment store and MPTT traversal"""

# a link to comment that is being replied, if one exists
parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

class MPTTMeta:
    # comments on one level will be ordered by date of creation
    order_insertion_by=['submit_date']

class Meta:
    ordering=['tree_id', 'lft']
```

comments/forms.py:

```
 from django import forms
 from django.contrib.admin import widgets
 from django_comments.forms import CommentForm
 from .models import MPTTComment

class MPTTCommentForm(CommentForm):
parent = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MPTTComment.objects.all(), required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput)

def get_comment_model(self):
    # Use our custom comment model instead of the built-in one.
    return MPTTComment

def get_comment_create_data(self):
    # Use the data of the superclass, and add in the parent field field
    data = super(MPTTCommentForm, self).get_comment_create_data()
    data['parent'] = self.cleaned_data['parent']
    return data
```

comments/templates/comments/_comments.html

```
{% load comments %}
{% load mptt_tags %}

{% get_comment_list for object as comments %}
{% if comments %}
{% recursetree comments %}
<div {% if request.REQUEST.c|add:"0" == node.id %}id="newly_posted_comment"{% endif %}>





        <a name="c{{ node.id }}"></a>
        {{ node.comment }}
        {{ node.user }}
        {{ node.submit_date|timesince }} ago
        <a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}#c{{ node.id }}">#</a>

    {% render_comment_form for object %}

{# recursion! children of a given comment #}

{% if not node.is_leaf_node %}
    {{ children }}
{% endif %}
</div>
{% endrecursetree %}
{% endif %}
{% render_comment_form for object %}
```

comments/templates/comments/form.html

```
{% load comments i18n %}
<div class="comment-form" id="comment-form-{{ node.id }}"
 {% if node.id %}
 style="display:none;"
 {% endif %}
>
<form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="post" id="comment-form-{{ node.id }}f">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.object_pk }}
{{ form.content_type }}
{{ form.timestamp }}
{{ form.security_hash }}
{% if node.id %}    
    <input type="hidden" name="parent" id="parent_id" value="{{ node.id }}" 
 />
{% endif %}
{{ form.comment }}
<input type="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

I have this tag setup in my posts/index.html template

```
 {% extends 'posts/base.html' %}
 {% block title %} Wiwik | What I Wish I Knew {% endblock %}
 {% load django_markdown %}

 {% block body %}

 <div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="main" id="show">
  {% for post in all_posts %}
 <div class="content">

    <h1 class="fof"><a href="{% url 'posts:detail' post.id post.post_title|slugify %}"> {{ post.post_title}}</a> </h1>
        <p><strong> Posted by </strong> <span class="idex"><a href="{% url 'posts:view_user' username=post.user.username user_id=post.user_id %}"><strong>{{ post.user.username }}</strong></a>&nbsp;<img src="{{ post.user.profile.avatar.url}}" class="post-thumb"/></span>
            <span class="biography cursive"> {{ post.user.profile.bio }}</span> <br/><span class="topic"> {{post.category}}</span>
            <br/>
            <span class="tiny"> on {{post.post_date}} <br/>With {{post.upvote}} Recommendations</span> </p>

             <a href="{% url 'posts:detail' post.id post.post_title|slugify %}">
                    {% if post.image %}
                        <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" class="img-responsive" id="mobi"/>
                    {% else %}
                    {% endif %}
            </a>
            <br/>

            <div class="test">{{ post.post_body|markdown }} </div>


           <br/>

           <a href="/posts/{{post.id}}/{{post.post_title}}/upvote/" method="post"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info"> Vote Up| {{ post.upvote }}</button></a> |
           <a href="/posts/{{post.id}}/{{post.post_title}}/down_vote/" method="post">Vote Down</a> |

          <button class="blab" type="button" style="background:none;border:none;color: #337AB7">Comments {{ post.comments.count }}</button>

           <br/>
           <br/>

           <div class="collapse" id="comm">
           {% for comment in comment.comments.all reversed %}
           {% if user.is_authenticated or comment.approved_comment %}
                <h4 class="author"><strong>{{ comment.author_comments.username }}</strong><span class="tiny"><strong>{{ comment.created_at }}</strong></span></h4>
                <div class="date">
                    {% if request.user.is_superuser %}
                    {% if not comment.approved_comment %}
                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'posts:comment_remove' pk=comment.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="{% url 'posts:comment_approve' pk=comment.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></a>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% else %}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                 <p><span class="text" id="new" >{{ comment.text|linebreaks }}</span></p>
                 <br/>
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
              </div>

        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    <br/>

            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <h3>Comment</h3>
          <div id="commentary"> {% with post as object %}{% include "comments/_comments.html" %}{% endwith %}</div>
        {% else %}
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'posts:login_user' %}">Add comment</a>
        <br/>
        <p>Please login to post a comment.</p>
        {% endif %}


      </div>
{% endfor %}
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="hline"></div>


    <p style="text-align: center;">WIWIK © 2016</p>
</div>

</div>

<div class="righto">
                <span class="st_twitter_large" displayText="Tweet"></span>
                <span class="st_facebook_large" displayText="Facebook">
</span>
                <span class="st_linkedin_large" displayText="LinkedIn">
</span>
                <span class="st_googleplus_large" displayText="Google+">
</span>
                <span class="st_email_large" displayText="Email"></span>
                <span class="st_sharethis_large" displayText="ShareThis">
</span>
            </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".blab").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.collapse').collapse('show');
    $(this).siblings('.collapse').collapse('hide');
    });
});
</script>


{% endblock %}
```

Extended from posts/base.html below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>


<title>{% block title %}Wiwik{% endblock %}</title>
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load comments %}
<meta name="viewport" content ="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=yes" url=#new />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'favicon.ico' %}"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy|Lato|Belgrano|Amethysta|IM+Fell+Great+Primer+SC|Open+Sans|Lora' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'posts/style.css' %}"/>
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ws.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ss.sharethis.com/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="{% static 'posts/js/main.js' %}"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'posts/js/truncator.js' %}"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $('.test').truncate({max_length: 100});
});
</script>

{% block extrahead %}

{{ block.super }}

{% include "comments/_ajax_comments.html" %}

{% endblock %}
```

The content posts are in the posts app

posts/models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    post_body = models.TextField(max_length=20000)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, related_name='hats')
    image = models.ImageField(default='static/wiwik.jpg', blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(default='')
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    upvote = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    down_vote = models.IntegerField(default=0)


def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('posts:detail', args=(self,), kwargs={"post_id": self.post_id})

def __str__(self):
    return self.post_title + ' - ' + self.post_body

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.post_title
```

Here is my link to the [stacktrace](http://dpaste.com/3TH3JPW)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please show the view.

Comment: I am not using any customized views in comments/models.py but running the built-in views and templates from django_comments also have script with js/ajax to render the page

Comment: The template shown in the stacktrace does not match any of the templates you've shown here.

Comment: I have added the index and base templates.